# Air Quality Analysis: ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I realise some analysis of air pollution with this **code**

```
Acri$Data <- as.POSIXct(Acri$Data, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
Acri$day <- as.numeric(format(Acri$Data, "%d"))
Acri$month <- as.numeric(format(Acri$Data, "%m"))
Acri$year <- as.numeric(format(Acri$Data, "%Y"))
library(waclr)
Acri$wd <- cardinal_direction_to_degrees(Acri$wd, north_is = 0)
#first plot
ggplot(data = Acri, aes(x = PM10, y = ws)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col = NO2)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(),panel.grid.minor=element_blank()) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "green", high = "red") +
  labs(title = "The distribution of NO2 under PM10 and wind speed",
       x = "PM10 (ug/m^3)", y = "Wind Speed (m/s)")
#second plot
ggplot(data = Acri, aes(month)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = NO2), width = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(),panel.grid.minor=element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 12, 1)) +
  labs(title = "The distribution of NO2 in each month",
       x = "Month")
#third plot
ggplot(data = Acri, aes(season)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = NO2), width = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(),panel.grid.minor=element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  labs(title = "The distribution of NO2 in each season",
       x = "Season")
```

If the first plot is displayed, then the second and third plots give the problem:
`Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`.

I tried by changing the variables with `as.factor` and `as.numeric`, but it doesn't work.

```
Acri$NO2 <- as.numeric(levels(Acri$NO2))[Acri$NO2]
Acri$PM10 <- as.numeric(levels(Acri$PM10))[Acri$PM10]
```

**Sample data**

```
Acri <- structure(list(NetC = c("Cosenza Provincia", "Cosenza Provincia", 
"Cosenza Provincia", "Cosenza Provincia", "Cosenza Provincia", 
"Cosenza Provincia", "Cosenza Provincia"), ID = c("IT2110A", 
"IT2110A", "IT2110A", "IT2110A", "IT2110A", "IT2110A", "IT2110A"
), Stat = c("Acri", "Acri", "Acri", "Acri", "Acri", "Acri", "Acri"
), Data = c("1/1/2021", "1/2/2021", "1/3/2021", "1/4/2021", "1/5/2021", 
"1/6/2021", "1/7/2021"), NO2 = c(27.84, 28.79, 17.76, 24.59, 
13.6, 7.34, 25.22), PM10 = c(22, 17.8, 25.3, 18.6, 13.7, 27.6, 
34.7), ws = c(1.47, 1.64, 2.52, 1.95, 3.07, 4.4, 1.72), wd = c("SSE", 
"SSE", "O", "ONO", "ONO", "ONO", "ONO")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

First plot
[image]
I would like to improve third plot as the first one.
[image]

Comment: `Acri$month <- format(Acri$date, "%m")` creates a character string for each month, e.g. `"01"` for January. This is different from the number 1, and is not considered by R to be a continuous variable. (What is halfway between 01 and 02?). Try `as.numeric(format(Acri$date, "%m"))`

Comment: I tried but I have this problem `Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion`

Comment: You first few lines seem inconsistent about whether the converted Date data is in a column called `Data` or `date`. Presumably, once you convert your dates into Date format with the first line, you'd want to extract month and day from that, ie from `Acri$Data`, not from `Acri$date`, which isn't defined anywhere in your sample data or code.

Comment: Suggestion: remove the loading of `waclr` (not on CRAN/BioC) and replace the `wd` field in your sample data with the _result_ from your call to `cardinal_direction_to_degrees`. It seems to be not relevant to the question, so we shouldn't have to install arbitrary packages just to generate irrelevant portions of the data.

Comment: I agree with you, I fixed this inconsistency. With dates the problem is solved, but now the second and third plots give the following error `Warning message:
The following aesthetics were dropped during statistical transformation: fill
ℹ This can happen when ggplot fails to infer the correct grouping structure in
  the data.
ℹ Did you forget to specify a group aesthetic or to convert a numerical
  variable into a factor?`

Comment: `Acri$PM10 <- as.factor(Acri$PM10)
Acri$NO2 <- as.factor(Acri$NO2)` This part of the code creates a strange plot. NO2 values ​​are displayed as discrete, but would like a continuous variable.

Comment: Factors in R are discrete. If you want to keep the underlying data as a continuous numeric value, don't convert them to factors.

Comment: I would like to improve second and third plots as the first one.